# using requires_channel: https causes a redirect loop

Tags: php, symfony, http-status-code-301, fosuserbundle

EVerything works fine locally on my machine which is running Ubuntu. However when code is ported to a scientific linux server (Apache), we are getting "redirect loop" error in the browser. We are using FosUserBundle

here are the access control lists:

```
 access_control:
        - { path: ^/practice/referral_listing, roles: ROLE_INTERNAL_PRACTICE_USER, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/practice/message_center, roles: ROLE_EXTERNAL_PRACTICE_USER, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/practice, roles: ROLE_PRACTICE_USER, requires_channel: https }


        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/referral, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https}
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Again any path that we try results in that.

How do I get about trouble shooting that? I tried using the chrome developer tool network tab and all it shows is a lot of 301 redirects.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by me using trusted_hosts option in the config.yml

Comment: what dit you set there? an ip?